# How to get the text value of a first column by button on click javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie html and javascript. I have clear code below

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Info1</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Info2</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Info3</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond();" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTdSecond() {

}
```

I want click a button I will get a text value of  second. Example : Info1, Info2, Info3. Please help me,

Comment: Thanks, but your way is not automatical, i choose an answer of "Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to pass the `this` value to the inline event handler,

```
<input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond(this);" type="button">
```

Then use the `this` context and traverse to the relevant element and collect its text,

```
function showTdSecond(_this) {
 alert(_this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.textContent);
}
```

Here you can read more about [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6uvrjcsz/)

Comment: You can put runnable snippets in your answer so no need for a link to another site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *cellIndex* property of the cell with the parent row to get the previous cell:

```js
function showTdSecond(el) {
  var cell = el.parentNode;
  alert(cell.parentNode.cells[cell.cellIndex - 1].textContent);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Info1</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond(this);" type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Info2</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond(this);" type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Info3</td>
    <td><input class="btn" value="Show" onclick="showTdSecond(this);" type="button"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer ! Give me more knowledge :) Thanks